# Proof of fixed point without using sequence

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be a function such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \frac{1}{2} |x-y|$. Then prove or disprove that $y=f(x)$ intersect the line $x=y$ exactly one time.

I can prove this result using sequence but I have tried it without using sequence. Please check the idea of my proof.

> If $f(0)=0$ then we are done. Let us assume $f(0)>0$, then $y=x$ intersect $y=\pm \frac{|x|}{2}+f(0)$ at $x=\frac{2f(0)}{3}$ and $2f(0)$. Now applying IVP on $f(x)-x$ we can conclude the result. Same for $f(0)<0$.

Is it correct? Is there any easier method to prove this?

Comment: I am guessing that you want to prove Banach Fixed point theorem a.k.a Banach Contraction principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) in an alternate way? This link might help you to develop further http://vmm.math.uci.edu/PalaisPapers/BanachContractionPrinciple.pdf

Comment: Look like you showed that they intersect, but did not show that they intersect exactly once.